# How to get param from one controller to another?

Tags: angularjs

My question is best explained when I straight go to the code.

HTML part:

```
<div class="panel panel-default post" ng-repeat="post in posts">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <a class="post-avatar thumbnail" href="/profile#/{[ post.profileID ]}">
          <div class="text-center">{[ user.fullname ]}</div>
        </a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I click on the /profile#/{[ post.profileID ]} link - it takes me to the profile page. All good here.

However, I am using ngView so I have separated it like this:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div>Some HTML stuff</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <div>Some HTML stuff</div>
</div>
```

My ngView makes use of the /profile#/{[ post.profileID ]} param and I use it to display whatever I have to display.

**The problem:**

I can get the profileID param in my angular controller but once I get it, how will I be able to pass it onto other controllers?

My controller looks like the below:

```
var profileApp = angular.module('profileApp', ['ngRoute']);

profileApp.config(function($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider
.when('/:id', {
    templateUrl : 'partial/profile/feed.html',
    controller  : 'mainController'
})

.when('/posts:id', {
    templateUrl : 'partial/profile/posts.html',
    controller  : 'postsController'
});

});

profileApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function($scope, $routeParams){

console.log($routeParams.id);

}]);

profileApp.controller('postsController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function($scope, $routeParams){

console.log($routeParams.id);

}]);
```

As you can see, I get get the param passed from the HTML link and use it in the mainController but how will I get the param to be a link in the col-md-3 (just like the original /profile#/{[ post.profileID ]})?

Hope this makes sense. It's has been driving me nuts!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did some research into this and I just ended up using services.

See below for the answer:

```
profileApp.service('globalParams', function() {
var profileID = '';

return {
    getProfileID: function() {
        return profileID;
    },
    setProfileID: function(value) {
        profileID = value;
        }
    };
});
```

You then pass the service into the dependencies in the controllers, like below:

```
profileApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', 'globalParams', function($scope, globalParams){
    //some code
};
```

And you can call the functions for getting and setting the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just edit your partial HTML pages and put the columns in it.
For `partial/profile/feed.html` :

```
<div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div>feed stuff</div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
  </div>
</div>
```

And `partial/profile/posts.html` could be :

```
<div>
  <div class="col-md-6">

  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div>posts stuff</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is what I am doing. The link to the ".when('/posts:id', {" will come from outside ("col-md-3") but the problem is that I can't construct the href URL without having the parameter. I hope I am making myself clear (it is a tricky issue)